# how to display quota info on lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen, tcsh

Is it possible to display user quota info on lock screen or any message at least?
because every time user lock in or unlock the first window he/she will look at is going to be lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

Till now there is no option to do that. If you wish you can download the source code of the unity-greeter and lightdm and try to do it yourself. But This is not a valid option right now.

Comment: I just thought of it by looking at how Windows 8, Android and iOS has it in the phone , displaying info on lock screen.

Comment: @san This is done in Ubuntu touch mobile but in Desktop/Server edition there is no such thing